# Detect when users log out of an application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, event-handling

If the application I'm working on, is there any way to tell when users press the `Logout` button?

Comment: Is another companent (c) a WPF control or a winform control?

Comment: You might want to have a look at that title, otherwise you might be on the wrong site...

Comment: yes. the component C is a WPF control

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with the paradigmatic differences between WPF and Winforms, but haven't ever written a line of WPF code, so this may not be applicable, but...  The way to accomplish this in WinForms would be to create a method on C (by subclassing C if it's not a class you can modify) and subscribing that method to the Click event on the button during your form's Load event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If form F has a reference to C, the F click handler can call a method on C.

If form F doesn't have a reference to C, expose a `LoggedOut` event on the first form, and either subscribe to it from C (if C has a reference to F) or use an event aggregator if C neither has a reference to the other.